# how to store the printed value in mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am printing values in the address bar using the get variable,it works perfectly, then my problem is i want store the printed values into a mysql table, but it only stores null values, please help me where i am going wrong in below attached code.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('header.php');
?>
<form name="cart.php">


<table>
<tr>
      <th> ID </th>
      <th> Vehicle Description </th>
      <th> Price </th>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td><?php echo $_GET['id']; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $_GET['name']; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $_GET['price']; ?> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$x=$_GET['id'];
$y=$_GET['name'];
$z=$_GET['price'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO products (id,description,price)
VALUES ('$x', '$y', '$y')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<form><input type="button" value="Go back" onClick="window.location.href='automobile_list.php'"></form>
</form> 

<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: print you $sql variable & check values are there or not

Comment: DON'T use variables from $_GET directly in your queries, this is a real security risk! Either escape the variables or use prepared statements.

Comment: Please use mysql_real_escape_string() function to get data in varable $x,$y,$z;

Comment: @Lakhan : can u please tell me how to use mysql_real_escape_string() function

Comment: Try this 
$x=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$y=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$z=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['price']);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('header.php');
$x=$_GET['id'];
$y=$_GET['name'];
$z=$_GET['price'];
?>
<form name="cart.php">


<table>
<tr>
      <th> ID </th>
      <th> Vehicle Description </th>
      <th> Price </th>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td><?php echo $x; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $y; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $z; ?> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO products (id,description,price)
VALUES ('$x', '$y', '$y')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<form><input type="button" value="Go back" onClick="window.location.href='automobile_list.php'"></form>
</form> 

<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

use the above code you will get your code working.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in query

so update that line as:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (id,description,price)
VALUES ('".$x."', '".$y."', '".$y."')";
```